# What is the difference between .astype() and .convert_dtypes() for pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What is the difference between `.astype()` and `.convert_dtypes()` for pandas? Which one is better to use and why?

Comment: Why dont you try google and show some effort to research them?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I use Google and official documentation but could not understand the exact difference. I am beginner in Python.

Comment: None is *better* per se. Depending on what you want. If you have a dataframe with all object columns for instance, and you want pandas to infer the best dtype, then `convert_dtypes` is handy. If you want to cast a given column to another dtype, go with `astype`

Comment: @yatu `convert_dtypes`can be used for particular series too.

Comment: Yes, but if you know the specific type you want to cast a column too, then just go with `astype` @vasili

Comment: astype allows you to specify the type you want to use, convert_dtypes will pick the dttype it thinks is best

Comment: @ChrisDoyle That is helpful. Thank you.